# Combinatorics: arrangement with permutations of $N$ elements

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have a combinatorics problem, and I am not sure of my answer, which seems stupidly large. Could anyone spot the mistake?

I have a set of $7$ unique elements. First, I need to know how many permutations I can get out of those $7$ elements.

```
(e1, e2, ....)
(e2, e1, ....)
```

If I am not mistaken, the answer is $7!$.

For each permutation, each element can take a certain number of value:

```
e1: 1 value
e2: 1 value
e3: 9 values
e4: 13 values
e5: 17 values
e6: 51 values
e7: 51 values
```

How many possible combination of $7$ values can I get?

```
e.g. If the permutation set is (e1, e3, e2, e5, e6, e4, e7), I could get:
(e1.val1, e3.val5, e2.val1, e5.val17, e6.val32, e7.val44)
```

I think it is:

```
7! * (9*13*17*51*51)
```

Then for each possible combination, $500$ steps are required (by an algorithm).
Thus, the total number of steps performed is:

```
7! * (9*13*17*51*51) * 500
```

If I had run this program on a powerfull workstation, I would have taken that number. But trillions of steps performed by my laptop in a few days seems a bit large.

Comment: Gflops are 1 billion operations a second. So, if you had a 1 Gflop device, it would take about 16 minutes 40 seconds to perform a trillion. To take more than 2 days straight, would take performance below, 5.8 Mflops and to take more than a week, you'd need 1.7 Mflops or less. The ratio of operation speeds, and use would  determine it.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee True, said like that :) I did not precise it, but each step is not elementary. It's a 100² matrix computation everytime + over stuff ^^

Comment: Thanks everyone for the confirmation!

Comment: In addition, the code is probably not hand-crafted to maximize FPU usage, so the GFlops value is not alone in determining the speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No everything is correct. Note that final value you get is ca. $1.30\times 10^{13}$, which is a formidable number.